# Ruby sort Hash By Inner Hash's count of same value

Tags: ruby

I have a hash of hashes and what I'm trying to accomplish is to sort the hash based on the count of the inner hash's count of the same value. So let's say this is my hash.

```
hash = { 
         "Run1"=>{"March 24, 2013"=>"failed", "March 23, 2013"=>"failed", "March 21, 2013"=>"failed", "March 19, 2013"=>"passed", "March 18, 2013"=>"passed"},
         "Run2"=>{"March 24, 2013"=>"failed", "March 23, 2013"=>"failed", "March 21, 2013"=>"failed", "March 19, 2013"=>"failed", "March 18, 2013"=>"failed"} 
       }
```

I want to sort the hash so the Run2 appears before Run1 since I'm trying to sort by the number of times a run "failed"

I'm thinking I need something like

```
hash.sort_by{|key, innerHash| innerHash.values.count('failed')}
```

Any help or suggestions is greatly appreciated

Comment: Count of 'failed' for Run1 = 3, for Run2 = 5. So code puts Run1 first. If you want to put mostly failed first you should count 'passed'.

Comment: Or if you have other statuses than passed/failed then you can reverse an array or pass negative values.

Comment: Your code will return them in ascending order so just reverse the returned array. hash.sort_by{|key, innerHash| innerHash.values.count('failed')}.reverse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lil fix:

```
hash.sort_by { |_,h| -h.values.count('failed') } # notice force negative
```

...and should work. Take in mind `sort_by` always returns an array, so maybe you'd want to:

```
sorted_hash = Hash[hash.sort_by { |_,h| -h.values.count('failed') }]
```

Comment: For reversing the sort `.reverse` can also be appended to the block: `sorted_hash = Hash[hash.sort_by{ |_,h| h.values.count('failed') }.reverse]`